# Can the NestJS class-validator convert the incoming object into the DTO I described?

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

```
export class UpdateUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsString()
  login: string;
}

  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
  @Override('updateOneBase')
  async updateOneOverride(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
    @Body() dto: UpdateUserDto,
  ) {
    console.log(dto);
    return this.service.updateOne(req, dto);
  }
```

Send body: `{ "login": "...", "email": "...", "password": "123" }`

Expecting console.log is to get a new DTO object instance, but I get exactly the same one.

Comment: Normally, `transform: true` should make that happen. There's a chance the pipe isn't running due to misaligned metadata of the `dto`'s type, but you'd have to check the `dist` for the compiled JS to check for that

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I thought it was weird too, but by adding ```whiteList: true``` key it worked